# Customization of Display Format for Datatables Plugin in Boostrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I want to move my search bar just next to the position of `Show entries`, that is, to the left position. I have this CSS style code applied to the filter input:

```css
.dataTables_filter {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}
```

It did move to left but not as expected, it just moved a bit to the left, in the center. Like in the next image:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this? Another acceptable solution is to just exchange the position of `Show entries` and `Search`. If that is possible, how can I do that?

Regarding my code, I have done nothing special and I only imported the library directly from the [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap) API. All I have is just a simple HTML code for displaying a table.

Comment: It's impossible to know the DOM by looking at an image and your attempt. Please show a minimal code example.

Comment: can you share the link where you have deployed it

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap framework? I have done some similar on some project using Bootstrap...

Comment: @Rafael All I have is simple HTML code with library imports from the [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap) API. I have written nothing special, whether it is HTML or JS.

Comment: Yes. I am using [Bootstrap datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap) API. @D.Smania

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), I will explain how to work with the display of elements related to the [datatables](https://datatables.net/) plugin. **Datatables** provides a way to configuring the [dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom), in other words, it let you configure how to display the different elements that form part of the table. These are identified like this:

> The built-in table control elements in **DataTables** are:
>
> **l** - length changing input control
> **f** - filtering input
> **t** - The table!
> **i** - Table information summary
> **p** - pagination control
> **r** - processing display element

And the default **dom** configuration for **Bootstrap** on **Datatables** are the next ones:

**Bootstrap 3:**

```
"<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>"
```

**Bootstrap 4:**

```
"<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'f>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>"
```

Now, the setup of the **dom** for **Bootstrap 3** is then traduced to the following `html` markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">l</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">f</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">tr</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5">i</div>
  <div class="col-sm-7">p</div>
</div>
```

That is why when you used the following `CSS` style on the **filtering control** it just goes to the middle of the page (note the filtering control **f** is wrapped inside a `col-sm-6` element):

```
.dataTables_filter {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
```

The good thing is that you can change this setup on **Datatables** initialization using the **dom** option. In your particular case, you can try out the next two setups, however, I invite you to play a little to found another one more convincing to you::

**Setup 1:**

```
"<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-3'f><'col-sm-6'>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>"
```

That will be traduced to next `html`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">l</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">f</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">tr</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5">i</div>
  <div class="col-sm-7">p</div>
</div>
```

Example in Bootstrap 3:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var domCfg = "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-3'f><'col-sm-6'>>" +
                 "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                 "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>";

    $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: domCfg
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**Setup 2:**

```
"<'row'<'col-sm-6'<'pull-left'l><'pull-left'f>><'col-sm-6'>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>"
```

That will be traduced to next `html`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="pull-left">l</div>
    <div class="pull-left">f</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">tr</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5">i</div>
  <div class="col-sm-7">p</div>
</div>
```

Example in Bootstrap 3:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var domCfg = "<'row'<'col-sm-6'<'pull-left'l><'pull-left'f>><'col-sm-6'>>" +
                 "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                 "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>";

    $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: domCfg
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Finally, as shown on the examples, and to apply a custom setup, just push a value on the **dom** option at the plugin initialization, like this:

```
var domSetup = "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-3'f><'col-sm-6'>>" +
               "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
               "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>";

$('#myTable').dataTable({
    /* Other initialization options */
    ...,
    "dom": domSetup
});
```

Note, you can do a fully display customization managing the **dom** option, I hope this guide helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `pull-left` class to your searchbar

Comment: Could you explain more with some code or probably a fiddle?

Comment: It's a Bootstrap class. Take a look at it https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-floats