# How to include Bootstrap 3 and JQuery Datatables in my project?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables, libraries

I have a question about including libraries in my project. The bootstrap 3 is the first library that is used on my project. Also, I need JQuery Datatables. I'm wondering if the code and way they implemented in my project is correct or I need to adjust. Here is example of my current home page that includes the libraries:

Home Page

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- *** Start: JS for DataTables. *** -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<!-- *** End: JS for DataTables. *** -->
```

Then I found this example: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap and there is very little information on what should be included. Also, there is no example on how to include buttons that I use in my code. If anyone know the way how to implement these libraries or if my code needs some adjustments please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I think it's true.

Comment: @shaghayeghsheykholeslami Is that enough or I still need my code above to include buttons?

Comment: you should implement buttons in your code, please explain more I couldn't understand what do you want to do.

Comment: I need to implement JQuery, Bootstrap 3, JQuery Datatables with buttons (Print, CSV, Excel, PDF and Copy). Does that make sense?

Comment: @espresso_coffee I have this all included in a project I have worked. Will come with the guide later if no one already answer it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct order for include the sources of **Datatables** (with Buttons extension) in order to integrate it with **Bootstrap** is the next:

**On the HEAD (Styles sources):**

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<path>/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<!-- Datatables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<path>/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<path>/buttons.bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

**On the BODY (script sources):**

```
<!-- jQuery JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path>/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path>/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path>/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path>/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path>/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path>/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path>/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path>/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path>/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path>/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path>/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path>/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path>/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
```

Note that `<path>` should be replace by the full path of the library. In my case I have it all locally, but you can use CDN repository too.

Also, remember that buttons only show if you configure correctly the `dom` option of the **Datatable** in the initialization step. My current config for the dom is this one ( where I have dropped the `l`: length change control):

```
dom = "< 'row' <'box-header' <'col-sm-6' B> <'col-sm-6' f> > >" +
      "< 'row' <'col-sm-12' tr> >" +
      "< 'row' <'col-sm-5' i> <'col-sm-7' p> >";
```

You can read more on site documentation: [Datatables dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)

Or on next explanation i have done before: [Customization of Display Format for Datatables Plugin in Boostrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095022/customization-of-display-format-for-datatables-plugin-in-boostrap-3/53104338#53104338)

Answer (score 1):

you can include like this

also refer this link [Datatable Github](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/integration/bootstrap/3/index.html)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dataTables.bootstrap.css">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#example').DataTable();
                } );
            </script>
```

Comment: What about buttons in JQuery Datatables? Are they automatically included with the code above? Or I still need the code that I have?

Answer (score 1):

Look this code for data table initialize

```
 var initTable1 = function () {
        var table = $('#sample_1');

        var oTable = table.dataTable({

            // Internationalisation. For more info refer to http://datatables.net/manual/i18n
            "language": {
                "aria": {
                    "sortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
                    "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
                },
                "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
                "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
                "infoEmpty": "No entries found",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtered1 from _MAX_ total entries)",
                "lengthMenu": "_MENU_ entries",
                "search": "Search:",
                "zeroRecords": "No matching records found"
            },

            // Or you can use remote translation file
            //"language": {
            //   url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/i18n/Portuguese.json'
            //},


            buttons: [
                { extend: 'print', className: 'btn dark btn-outline' },
                { extend: 'copy', className: 'btn red btn-outline' },
                { extend: 'pdf', className: 'btn green btn-outline' },
                { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn yellow btn-outline ' },
                { extend: 'csv', className: 'btn purple btn-outline ' },
                { extend: 'colvis', className: 'btn dark btn-outline', text: 'Columns'}
            ],

            // setup responsive extension: http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/
            responsive: true,

            //"ordering": false, disable column ordering 
            //"paging": false, disable pagination

            "order": [
                [0, 'asc']
            ],

            "lengthMenu": [
                [5, 10, 15, 20, -1],
                [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
            ],
            // set the initial value
            "pageLength": 10,

            "dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12'B>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>", // horizobtal scrollable datatable

            // Uncomment below line("dom" parameter) to fix the dropdown overflow issue in the datatable cells. The default datatable layout
            // setup uses scrollable div(table-scrollable) with overflow:auto to enable vertical scroll(see: assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.js). 
            // So when dropdowns used the scrollable div should be removed. 
            //"dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12'T>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",
        });
    }
```

there is implement of buttons.
finally you shoud initialize your data table in documnet ready like this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    initTable1();
});
```