# Jquery Datatables search and pagination wrong location

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, pagination

I have created an html page using jquery datatable. All is ok, but the search , number of record drop down and pagination are been show at wrong location
Click here to see the image which show the issue[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRCRN.png)

As seen in pic , i need to fix it . can you please let me know what is wrong,.

My code is

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Voucher Registeration</title>
    <style>
      .dataTables_paginate {
          float: left;
       margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
 </br>
    <h1><center>Voucher Registeration</center></h1>
 <table id="campaignDE" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
   <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">#</th>
    <th scope="col">Market</th>
    <th scope="col">Code</th>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">VoucherUsed</th>
    <th scope="col">VoucherUnused</th>
    <th scope="col">VocTag</th>
    <th scope="col">Email</th>
    <th scope="col">Threshold</th>
    <th scope="col">CreatedDate</th>
    <th scope="col">LatestSentDate</th>
  </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   %%[
     var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @i , @ReturnClause
     set @ReturnClause   = 1
     set @numRowsToReturn = 0  
     set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("CampaignRegisteration", @numRowsToReturn,"Market asc, LatestSentDate desc","Return",@ReturnClause)
     set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
     if @rowCount > 0 then 
      for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
        var @CampaignNo , @CampaignName , @VoucherUsed, @VoucherUnused, @CreadedDate , @VocTag ,@LatestSentDate, @Market
        set @row        = row(@rows, @i)  
             set @CampaignNo       = field(@row,"CampaignNo")
             set @CampaignName   = field(@row,"CampaignName")
             set @VoucherUsed    = field(@row,"VoucherUsed")
             set @VoucherUnused   = field(@row,"VoucherUnused")
             set @CreadedDate     = field(@row,"CreatedDate")
             set @ThresholdEMail   = field(@row,"Email")
             set @ThresholdValue   = field(@row,"Threshold")
             set @VocTag        = field(@row,"VocTag")
             set @LatestSentDate   = field(@row,"LatestSentDate")
             set @Market        = field(@row,"Market") 
     ]%%
     <tr>
    <th scope="row">%%=v(@i)=%%</th>
    <td>%%=v(@Market)=%%</td>      
       <td>%%=v(@CampaignNo)=%%</td>
       <td>%%=v(@CampaignName)=%%</td>
       <td>%%=v(@VoucherUsed)=%%</td>
       <td>%%=v(@VoucherUnused)=%%</td>
       <td>%%=v(@VocTag)=%%</td>
       <td>%%=v(@ThresholdEMail)=%%</td>
       <td>%%=v(@ThresholdValue)=%%</td>
       <td>%%=v(@CreadedDate)=%%</td>
       <td>%%=v(@LatestSentDate)=%%</td>
     </tr>
    %%[ next @i ]%%
   %%[ else ]%%
    <br>No Data Available</br>
  %%[ endif ]%%
   </tbody>
 </table>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#campaignDE').DataTable( {
           "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "filter": true
       } );
  } );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want the

1. Number of record per page and search to appear before the table (top right conner )
2. The pagination below table
3. Also on the columns i would like to give some tooltip

can you please let me know the how to do it

Comment: Check next: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095022/customization-of-display-format-for-datatables-plugin-in-boostrap-3/53104338#53104338. I have explained there how to manipulate the display format for DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the CSS for dataTables_paginate, and use the [DOM](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) tools to move the controls around.